# SQL-query - how to combine different search queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about querying in MySql through PHPmyadmin. I have a database that contains several tables. One of these tables contains the match-information of a sports game. This “Game” table has the columns “gameid”, “pouleid”, “hometeamnumber”, “awayteamnumber”, “gamedate”.

Then I have another table “Team” in which the teamdata is stored.  This table has only three columns: “teamnumber”, “clubname”, “teamname”.

Now I want to make a sql-query on this database. In the result I want to display the “gameid”, “homeclubname”, “hometeamname”, “awayclubname”, “awayteamname” and “gamedate”. To get the homeclubname and hometeamname I need to get the “hometeamnumber” from the Game table and compare it to the “teamnumber” in the “Team” table. The same goes for the awayclubname and the awayteamname.

But I can only manage to get only the homeclub/team or the awayclub/team in my query. Therefore I use the following SQL-statement:

```
“SELECT gameid, pouleid, hometeamnumber, clubname, teamname, awayteamnumber, gamedate
FROM Game, Team
WHERE Game.hometeamnumber = Team.teamnumber”
```

But this will only give me the homeclubname and the hometeamname. Ideal I would also want the awayclubname and the awayteamname. But to get this information I would have to look in the table Team. The following query obviously won’t work.

```
“SELECT gameid, pouleid, hometeamnumber, clubname, teamname, awayteamnumber, gamedate
FROM Game, Team
WHERE Game.hometeamnumber = Team.teamnumber
AND Game.awayteamnumber = Team.teamnumber”
```

How can I do this in one sql-query?

Comment: Changing AND to OR would not work cause I need both the home and away team. Using JOIN is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following will get the team data for both teams within a specific game

```
SELECT
    Team.*
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Team
ON Team.teamnumber IN (Game.hometeamnumber,Game.awayteamnumber)
WHERE Game.gameid = 123
```

Depending on what you are producing there are a variety of alterations that could be made, the above would be suitable when displaying information about a single game.  If trying to display a large table of results there are other methods that could be used, so please clarify the question if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use joins to return the data you want.

Just eyeballing it quickly suggests something like:

```
SELECT gameid, pouleid, 
hometeamnumber, #HomeTeam.clubname as HomeTeamClubName, #HomeTeam.teamname as HomeTeamName,
awayteamnumber, #AwayTeam.clubname as AwayTeamClubName, #AwayTeam.teamname as AwayTeamName, 
gamedate
FROM Game
INNER JOIN Team as #HomeTeam
on hometeamnumber = #HomeTeam.teamnumber
INNER JOIN Team as #AwayTeam
on awayteamnumber = #AwayTeam.teamnumber
```

You should be able to edit / improve this for your specific needs.